# How to convert string "$double_number" to double number

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to objective c and I have lot of string in format "$99.99" ( "$double_number" ).
How to summarise all prices and get one real number ?

Comment: you want it in integer or double/float?

Comment: @Anoop Vaidya I want double, to extract that value from string ( for example "$99.99" to get 99.99 )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One quick solution is to remove `$` and find the doubleValue as :

```
NSString *str = @"$99.99"; 
str = [str substringFromIndex:1];
double price = [str doubleValue];
NSLog(@"--> %.2f", price); //return 99.99
```

Note: `double` value has more precision (value after decimal) as you need only two, I used `.2f`.

Comment: can't really argue with something so simple +1

Comment: Just once I thought to use `NSNumberFormatter` to make it complex yet real time currency conversion.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *stringValue = @"$99.99";
NSString *price = [stringValue substringFromIndex:1];
double price = [price doubleValue];
NSLog(@"price : %.2f", price);
```

Explanation:

First remove the dollar symbol and next convert it to double using doubleValue

Comment: you can edit the answer to meet his requirement by putting `.2f` since he want upto two decimals.

Answer (score 1):

Check if string has prefix as dollar sign  using `NSStrings` `hasPrefix`

```
NSString *strWithDollar = @"$4.95";
if([strWithDollar hasPrefix:@"$"])
{
    strWithDollar = [strWithDollar substringFromIndex:1];
}
double price = [strWithDollar doubleValue];
NSLog(@"price : %.2f", price); //return 4.95
```